# componentDidUpdate() updating when state changes even if not in condition

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have a unread property in my database that is used to calculate `unreadCount`. Now I am using Firebase and I have added a listener as to when the unread property changes in my `componentDidMount()`. Whenever the unread in firebase changes, it updates `props.user.unread` inside my `componentDidUpdate()`, which looks like -

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if(prevProps.user.unread !== this.props.user.unread ) {
        console.log("PREV PROPS",prevProps.user.unread)
        console.log("CURR PROPS",this.props.user.unread)
        this.setState({unreadCount:0})
        this.handleUnread(this.props.user.unread)
    }
}
```

and `this.handleUnread` looks like-

```
handleUnread(obj) {
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            console.log("OBJ",obj[key])
            if(obj[key] > 0) {
                this.setState({unreadCount: this.state.unreadCount +1})
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here in `handleUnread(obj)`, I am updating `state.unreadCount` and this causes `componentDidUpdate(prevProps)` to run again even if my condition is not satisfied. my console logs look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7Nfl.png). Clearly `componentDidUpdate` is being called multiple times even if condition is not satisfied. My state changes every time `handleUnread()` is invoked and my question is does it invoke `handleUnread()` again in `componentDidUpdate`?

If so why as if condition is not being satisfied. Also is there any other way to solve this problem instead of using **state** to measure `unreadCount`?

### Update

`handleUnread` is being called even with no state changes inside it and inside `componentDidUpdate`.

Answer (score 0):

After some research on React hooks, I found out that they are asynchronous in nature. Being asynchronous in nature it is a bad idea to call `this.setState()` inside a loop. So I fixed by adding `prevState` field in my `componentDidUpdate` and set my state only after the loop completes.